# Magento categories export and import with structure and id

Tags: magento, csv, import, export, categories

Is there a way to export and import categories with structure and ids? Anyone maybe have already written code?

Comment: yup!<br/>
Try
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86113/import-export-all-categories-using-csv-file-without-extension James Niland<br/>
nilandtrading.com